# How do I update a single row in a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How can I update one row?

I have in a SQL Server database 34 rows f.e `SYSTIMESTATE (14.10.2014 08:01:15:000)` and I will replace this with `(04.11.2014 08:01:15:000)`

How can I do this? With the `UPDATE` statement?

Here is the `SELECT` statement:

```
select * from EXDOCS where SYSTIMESTATE = '14.10.2014 08:01:15:000'
```

Comment: you can check the `UPDATE` statement's syntax

Comment: Updating a single row (as per title) by using a datetime is a very dangerous thing to do if it's not a unique key in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE EXDOCS
SET SYSTIMESTATE = '04.11.2014 08:01:15:000'
WHERE SYSTIMESTATE = '14.10.2014 08:01:15:000'
```

Also learn how to come up with a solution yourself: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Answer (score 1):

Yes,`update`is what you want:

```
UPDATE EXDOCS 
SET   SYSTIMESTATE = '04.11.2014 08:01:15:000'
WHERE SYSTIMESTATE = '14.10.2014 08:01:15:000'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE EXDOCS  
SET SYSTIMESTATE = '04.11.2014 08:01:15:000'  
WHERE SYSTIMESTATE = '14.10.2014 08:01:15:000'
```